# Axios call, getting response data into select options with vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

All I'm trying to do here is figure out how to get the response data values tied into my multiselect `options` but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

THe console log is properly showing my returned results so I know they're being returned but I don't know how to tie them into my multiselect options.

For instance, if I type 'Day' into my multiselect, my axios call performs an autocomplete function and gets matching options so my console shows:

```
 0:
    tag_id:  "1001"
    tag_data: "First Day"
 1:
    tag_id:   "1002"
    tag_data: "Second Day"
```

SO how can I get those returned values into my options?

```
  <div id="tagApp">
      <multiselect
      v-model="value"
      :options="options"
      :loading="loading"
      :multiple="true"
      :taggable="true"
      @search-change="val => read(val)"
      ></multiselect>
  </div>

new Vue({
      components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
      },
      el: "#tagApp",
      data() {
        return{
            value: [],
            loading: false,
            options: []
        }

      },
      methods: {
        read: function(val){
            //console.log('searched for', val);
          if (val) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.options = [];

            const self = this;
            console.log(val);

            axios.get('campaigns/search',{params: {query: val}})
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.options = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
            });

          } else {
            this.options = [];
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: What format is response.data coming in as? json?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is JSON

Comment: Can you show me the **multiselect** component? What does it expect in it's options prop? A list of strings?

Comment: The multiselect component is in the code currently. It's expecting the string data from the JSON object, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using objects as the options, you'll need to pass `label` and `track-by`  properties to the multiselect component. See the docs [here](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-single-select-object)

```
<multiselect
  v-model="value"
  label="tag_data"
  track-by="tag_id"
  :options="options"
  :loading="loading"
  :multiple="true"
  :taggable="true"
  @search-change="val => read(val)"
></multiselect>
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize those were needed for that but it makes sense. Only question: It seems now that once I make a selection a tag, then selecting another clears all tags. Basically making a tag considers them all selected. Is it clear in my code why that's happening?

Comment: Actually, nevermind that's working now. HOwever, it's not allowing the creation of a new tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `label` property as well as the `track-by` property. In my example, `title` is a property on the object I am using as `options`, so you'll need to use a property name that exists in the array you're using as `options`..

CodePen mirror: https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/ROVqZK?editors=1010

```js
Vue.component("multiselect", window.VueMultiselect.default);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: [],
    options: []
  },
  mounted() {
    var self = this;
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_start=1&_end=10")
      .then(response => {
        self.options = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <label class="typo__label">Simple select / dropdown</label>
  <multiselect 
    v-model="value" 
    :height="300"
    :options="options" 
    :multiple="true" 
    :close-on-select="false" 
    :clear-on-select="false" 
    :preserve-search="true" 
    placeholder="Pick some" 
    label="title" 
    track-by="title" 
    :preselect-first="false"
  >
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }"><span class="multiselect__single" v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen">{{ values.length }} options selected</span></template>
  </multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value }}</code></pre>
</div>
```